# Custom output for user profile list

Tags: views

I have a "`user list`" view, which displays an "`unformatted list`" of user accounts.

While the row display is controlled via `views-view-unformatted.tpl.php` and customizing it works, the row plugin "`user`" in `views/modules/user/views_plugin_row_user_view.inc` directly outputs the user profile into the row.

Now as I already have a customized `user-profile.tpl.php` I cannot customize it for both view row and user profile page...

How do I implement custom display of user profiles in the user list, then?

Answer (score 0):

It's trivial, but—did you try changing the row plugin to Fields instead of User?
With fields, you have granular control over the display of the user profile, so this might in effect be what you're looking for.